# unmatched block nesting : main [ASM]

Tags: assembly, masm

I searched up the error and it says that it does not have a matching end. I've been trying to fix it for quite awhile now, but I don't see what it means by it doesn't have a matching end when I just ended it at the end.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.386
.model flat, stdcall, small
.stack 4096
.stack 32
.stack 100h
ExitProcess PROTO, deExitCode:DWORD

.data
fib DB ?

.code
main PROC

mov eax,@data
mov eds, eax
lea esi, fib
mov eah, 01h
int 21h
sub eal, 30h

mov ecl,eal
mov eax,00h
mov ebx,01h
mov[esi], eax

inc esi
mov [esi],ebx
inc esi
sub ecl,02h

L1:
add eax, ebx
mov ebx, [esi]
inc esi
loop L1

int 3h
end
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing code written for Windows and code written for DOS. You can't do that - pick one or the other. Note that all those `.` directives are unnecessary since `Irvine32.inc` sets them for you.

Comment: In particular you can't just take 16-bit code and tack an `e` onto every register name.  There are no such registers as `eds`, `eal`, and so on, and even if there were, segmentation is totally different in 32-bit mode (and should be ignored in most applications).  It needs a proper rewrite.  I suspect these errors are confusing the assembler into giving a misleading error message.

Comment: @NateEldredge I fixed it, but then it says that there is a symbol type conflict at "mov eax, @data". I tried changing it to mov eax, fib, but then it says "instruction operands must be the same size"

Comment: Yep, `fib` is a byte (`db`) but `eax` is a 32-bit register.  Do you want to load 1 byte, or 4, and where do you want to put it?  But anyway it seems like you're just randomly changing stuff to make it build, without attention to what the code will actually do.  To emphasize Michael's point, the code as you have it based on the MS-DOS `int 21h` API is never going to work with Irvine32.  You need to start over.